# Java Random Percentage Chance

Tags: java, random, percentage

Someone can u help me to show how to make a probability / chance with percentage ?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = new Random().nextInt(10);
        if (a >= 6) {
            // 60% chance
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("You got a passive power");
        } else if (a >= 3) {
            // 30% chance
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("You got an active power");
        } else if (a >= 1) {
            // 10% chance
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("You got an ultimate power");
        } else {
            // <10% chance (maybe)
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println("You blessed with all powers.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is my program correct ?

**Ty**

Comment: Your question is so confusing I don't know where to even begin. Your percentages are wrong. What you have for a 60% chance is actually 40% chance. What you have for a 30% chance is actually 30% chance (somehow). What you have for 10% chance is actually 20% chance. What is less than 10% chance in this context? Google "probability formula" and try doing it yourself, and you will see that not only the program is incorrect, but the question is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your program is not correct.

When you call `nextInt(10)`, you get a number in range 0 to 9, inclusive. You then segment that into the probability ranges you want, without reusing a number:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  └──────────────┘  └─────┘  ╵
    6 / 10 = 60%      30%   10%
```

Which means the code should be:

```java
int a = new Random().nextInt(10);
if (a < 6) {
    // 60% chance
} else if (a < 9) {
    // 30% chance
} else {
    // 10% chance
}
```

Or you could go the other way:

```java
//   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
//   ╵  └─────┘  └──────────────┘
//  10%   30%          60%

int a = new Random().nextInt(10);
if (a >= 4) {
    // 60% chance
} else if (a >= 1) {
    // 30% chance
} else {
    // 10% chance
}
```

Comment: And how to do that without the `Random` class or any other libraries?

Comment: @Dr.jacky , Hi, the case here is "chance in percentage". I think we all need some random number to be compared with the percentage condition. If you don't mean I ask, what are you trying to achieve without Random class ?